# How to use FormData in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

Hi just learn to use js and react-native. I cant use FormData it always shows unsupported bodyinit type. I want to send text rather then JSON.stringify. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
var data = new FormData()
data.append('haha', 'input')

fetch('http://www.mywebsite.com/search.php', { 
  method: 'post',
  body: data
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
  console.log('Fetch Success==================');
  console.log(responseData);

  var tempMarker = [];
  for (var p in responseData) {
   tempMarker.push({
    latitude: responseData[p]['lat'],
    longitude: responseData[p]['lng'] 
   })
  }

  this.setState({
    marker: tempMarker
  });

})
.catch((error) => {
  console.warn(error);
})
.done();
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: "unsupported bodyinit type"

Comment: When handling with FormData in react-native `make sure not to have the react-native debugger attached`. Otherwise you will have issues.

Answer (score 101):

Here is my simple code FormData with react-native to post request with string and image.

I have used react-native-image-picker to capture/select photo
 [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker)

```
let photo = { uri: source.uri}
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("product[name]", 'test')
formdata.append("product[price]", 10)
formdata.append("product[category_ids][]", 2)
formdata.append("product[description]", '12dsadadsa')
formdata.append("product[images_attributes[0][file]]", {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'})
```

**NOTE** you can change `image/jpeg` to other content type. You can get content type from image picker response.

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.101:3000/products',{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: formdata
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("image uploaded")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

Comment: May I know where is FormData class come from? I checked react-native-image-picker, it is not inside

Comment: FormData is came with react-native. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/FormData.js

Comment: According to the MSDN doc, `FormData` should have a `set()` method (it does in Chrome for instance), but apparently this is not available in React Native, so the solution is indeed to use `append()`

Comment: If you have issues with the above, try adding a "boundary" to the content-type `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=someArbitraryUniqueString`

Comment: @bun: Im following your example above, but the req.body in server side is always empty, kindly help

Comment: @optimus you are using node js as your server side?

Comment: @bunhouth: yes, im uisng node js

Comment: @bunhouth: yes sure im using multer 

`exports.create = function(req,res, next) {

  upload(req,res, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Post cannot be created.' });
    }
    console.log(req.body) 
   console.log(req.files)
    const title = req.body.title;
    const content = req.body.content;
    const imageUrl = req.files;
   
     posts.save((err, category) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
       res.status(201).json({
          category: category
        });
      });
  })
`
}

Comment: @optimus did u allow post request with multipart

Comment: @bunhouth: yes the above code is working in postman and in angular2(web).

Comment: This is working great. It should be the accepted answer!

Comment: I found that the `type: 'multipart/form-data'` part is crucial if you want your FormData fetching to work on Android …

Comment: saved my day. was not sending { type: 'image/jpeg' } the server parsers the image part also field but not a file. thanks.

Comment: @optimus had the same exact issue almost gone crazy. use original FormData
by running [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57276084/5674583) anywhere in the init files of your project. This is the only solution worked for me

Comment: how to convert your ```photo.uri``` to binary?

Comment: @MichaelMao you don't need to convert, you can get base64 image data from image picker. You can check your image picker lib about that option.
Ex. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#the-response-object

Comment: @optimus did you ever find a solution? I am also following the code above and getting an empty obj for `req.body` in Node.

Comment: @optimus did you using multer for support form-data(express)?

Comment: Is there a way that I can use the the same thing using a loop in react native rather than appending all items one by one?

Comment: @STBox you can check https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata

Comment: If all attributes passed is for product entity, there is no need to put everything in a product array, unless the API is really expecting you to pass them as array.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to set custom content-type for formData item:

```
var img = {
    uri : 'file://opa.jpeg',
    name: 'opa.jpeg',
    type: 'image/jpeg'
};
var personInfo = {
    name : 'David',
    age: 16
};

var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('personInfo', {
    "string": JSON.stringify(personInfo), //This is how it works :)
    type: 'application/json'
});

fdata.append('image', {
    uri: img.uri,
    name: img.name,
    type: img.type
});
```

Comment: It works! Without this solution all requests was sent with Content-Type: application/octet-stream instead of multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me

```
var serializeJSON = function(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(function (keyName) {
    return encodeURIComponent(keyName) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[keyName])
  }).join('&');
}

var response = fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: serializeJSON({
    haha: 'input'
  })
});
```

Comment: how can i just use text? not json

Comment: var response = fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body:encodeURIComponent("haha") + '=' + encodeURIComponent("input")
});

Answer (score 6):

Providing some other solution; we're also using `react-native-image-picker`; and the server side is using `koa-multer`; this set-up is working good:

**ui**

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {}
      else if (response.error) {}
      else if (response.customButton) {}
      else {
        this.props.addPhoto({ // leads to handleAddPhoto()
          fileName: response.fileName,
          path: response.path,
          type: response.type,
          uri: response.uri,
          width: response.width,
          height: response.height,
        });
      }
    });

handleAddPhoto = (photo) => { // photo is the above object
    uploadImage({ // these 3 properties are required
      uri: photo.uri,
      type: photo.type,
      name: photo.fileName,
    }).then((data) => {
      // ...
    });
  }
```

**client**

```
export function uploadImage(file) { // so uri, type, name are required properties
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file);

  return fetch(`${imagePathPrefix}/upload`, { // give something like https://xx.yy.zz/upload/whatever
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  }
  ).then(
    response => response.json()
  ).then(data => ({
    uri: data.uri,
    filename: data.filename,
  })
  ).catch(
    error => console.log('uploadImage error:', error)
  );
}
```

**server**

```
import multer from 'koa-multer';
import RouterBase from '../core/router-base';

const upload = multer({ dest: 'runtime/upload/' });

export default class FileUploadRouter extends RouterBase {
  setupRoutes({ router }) {
    router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), async (ctx, next) => {
      const file = ctx.req.file;
      if (file != null) {
        ctx.body = {
          uri: file.filename,
          filename: file.originalname,
        };
      } else {
        ctx.body = {
          uri: '',
          filename: '',
        };
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: When using this I get: `Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but was 'file'
`

Answer (score 4):

## Usage of formdata in react-native

I have used `react-native-image-picker` to select photo. In my case after choosing the photp from mobile. I'm storing it's info in component `state`. After, I'm sending  `POST` request using `fetch` like below

```
const profile_pic = {
  name: this.state.formData.profile_pic.fileName,
  type: this.state.formData.profile_pic.type,
  path: this.state.formData.profile_pic.path,
  uri: this.state.formData.profile_pic.uri,
}
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('first_name', this.state.formData.first_name);
formData.append('last_name', this.state.formData.last_name);
formData.append('profile_pic', profile_pic);
const Token = 'secret'

fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/profile/', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Authorization: `Token ${Token}`
    },
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using Expo SDK 42 (react-native v0.63). And I was using the `expo-document-picker` library to pick the documents & upload to server.

I am assuming you want to use `FormData` to upload some kind of file.

This is the code I am using to open the picker & get the metadata about the file.

```js
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';

const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
    type: 'image/*',
    copyToCacheDirectory: false,
    multiple: false,
});

if (result.type === 'success') {
    const name_split = result.name.split('.');
    const ext = name_split[name_split.length - 1];
    result.type = helper.get_mime_type(ext);
    delete result.size;
}
```

(You can write your function to get the mime type from the file extension or use some library from npm)

`result` has the following info at this point:

```js
result.uri // "content://path/to/file.ext"
result.name // filename
result.type // the mime type of the file such as "image/png"
```

And this is the code I am using to upload the file to server using `axios` library:

```js
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('custom_param', 'value');
formdata.append('file', result); // 'result' is from previous code snippet

const headers = {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
};

const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'your backend endpoint',
    headers: headers,
    data: formdata,
};
return await axios.request(axiosopts);
```

Comment: good explaination., solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use **react-native-image-picker** and **axios (form-data)**

```
uploadS3 = (path) => {
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('files',
        { uri: path, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' }
    );

    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: YOUR_URL,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        data: data,
    };

    axios(config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

react-native-image-picker

```
selectPhotoTapped() {
    const options = {
        quality: 1.0,
        maxWidth: 500,
        maxHeight: 500,
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
        },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
        //console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel) {
            //console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
            //console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
            //console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
            let source = { uri: response.uri };
             
            // Call Upload Function
            this.uploadS3(source.uri)

            // You can also display the image using data:
            // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
            this.setState({
                avatarSource: source,
            });
            // this.imageUpload(source);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Adding  `Accept: "application/json"` did the trick!

Comment: What is `uri` in `{ uri: path, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' }`, are you using [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/File#propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9s) because it is not documented there. Do you have a source documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a long time an answer that solve the problem and this is the way I did it

I take the file with expo-document-picker

```
const pickDocument = async (tDocument) => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync();
    result.type = mimetype(result.name);
    if (result.type === undefined){
      alert("not allowed extention");
      return null;
    }
    let formDat = new FormData();
    formDat.append("file", result);
    uploadDoc(formDat);
  };

  const mimetype = (name) => {
    let allow =  {"png":"image/png","pdf":"application/json","jpeg":"image/jpeg", "jpg":"image/jpg"};
    let extention = name.split(".")[1];
    if (allow[extention] !== undefined){
      return allow[extention]
    }
    else {
      return undefined
    }
  }

const uploadDoc = (data) =>  {
    fetch("MyApi", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response =>{
      if (response.result === 1) {
        //somecode
      } else {
        //somecode
      }
    });
  }
```

this is because android doesn't manage the mime-type of your file so if you put away the header "Content-type" and instead you put the mime-type on the file it gonna send the correct header

works on IOS an Android

Answer (score 0):

I have used form data with [ImagePicker](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker) plugin.
and I got it working please check below code

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);
  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    fetch(globalConfigs.api_url+"/gallery_upload_mobile",{
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
      ,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: response.data.toString(),
      fileName: response.fileName
    })
      }).then(response => {
        console.log("image uploaded")
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })  
  }
});
```

Comment: How can you send multipart content via JSON (check your Content-Type header)

Comment: @AzeemHassni update my answer as per your review as I was getting images in base64 string thats why used json

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting multipart: boundry not found error you can use fetch api instead of axios it works with fetch but not with axios for some reason.

```
fetch('http://192.168.10.38:8080/api/auth/register',{
 method: 'post',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
 body: formdata
 }).then(response => {
    console.log("success")
 }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
```

})
});

Answer (score 0):

works for me.

```
// imageObject
{
  name: string,
  type: string,
  uri: string,
}

// body  
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', postData.name);
formData.append('properties', {
    string: JSON.stringify(postData.properties),
    type: 'application/json',
});

postData.slides.forEach(v => {
    formData.append('slideImages', v);
  });
formData.append('detailImage', postData.detailImage);

// request
requestInit: {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).