# Upload image using formdata in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i upload file to server using react-native's fetch api
Need to achieve something similar to this-

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRAxza9ew2ADaYHn5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="66154520.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryRAxza9ew2ADaYHn5--
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native.

Comment: We use base64 to upload images from device to server. This way data that we send is always same type - no need to define different type for each different format image (jpg, png, bmp ... etc.). And we never had any issues with that, on server just convert back from base64.

Answer (score 20):

You didn't show any kind of code, but in theory...

You should pass url from something like `ImagePicker` or `CameraRoll` (which should look similar to `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/shj15791-4v61-67g6-z1b6-v8451z956j5k.jpg`) to `formData` and then pass it along with the request:

```
const form = new FormData();

form.append('image', {
  uri: "file:///...",
  type: 'image/jpg',
  name: 'image.jpg',
});

fetch('https://example.com/api/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: form
});
```

Comment: It doesnt give the required(in the question) output. rather it displays `[object Object]`

Comment: so you will get a from data with file uri not file stream/binary/blob. I don't know how it can work

Comment: Fetch will covert the local URI to a stream/binary/blob for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. tested in Android and iOS for camera and gallary

```
const os = Platform.OS

    let data = new FormData();
    if (os == 'android') {
      const fileName = new Date().getTime() + getExtention(mime);
      let fileInfo = '';
      await RNFS.copyFile(uri, RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + '/' + fileName).catch(e => {
        fileInfo = undefined;
      });
      
      if (!fileInfo) {
        fileDetail = await RNFS
          .stat(RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + '/' + fileName)
          .catch(e => {});
        data.append('file', {
          name: getFilename(fileDetail.path),
          type: payload.file.type,
          uri: 'file://' + fileDetail.path,
        });
      }

    } else {
      let  localPath= uri;
      if (!localPath.includes('private')) {
        localPath = localPath.replace('/var', '/private/var');
      }
      data.append('file', {
        name: getFilename(localPath),
        type: mime,
        uri: localPath.replace('file://', ''),
      });
    }
```

---

```
 export const getFilename = url => {
      return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    };
    
export const getExtention = mime => {
  switch (mime) {
    case 'application/pdf':
      return '.pdf';
    case 'image/jpeg':
      return '.jpg';
    case 'image/jpg':
      return '.jpg';
    case 'image/png':
      return '.png';
    default:
      return '.jpg';
  }
};
```