# how to upload image or pdf file with form-data in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i found some libraries but i am not sure which one is suitable and stable for me.

i am implementing like email attachment with form-data.

Choose uploading files from gallery or file Manage on Android device and upload to server.

could you recommend nice library? thank you !

**what i have found**

https://github.com/kaancelen/react-native-nononsense-file-picker

https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker

https://github.com/farmisen/react-native-file-uploader

https://github.com/huangzuizui/react-native-file-opener

and so on..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use FormData in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first use a document picker - use
react-native-document-picker
https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker
Then create a form data object in callback of document picker

```
data = new FormData();

data.append('resource', {
    name: res.fileName,
    uri: res.uri, type: res.type
});
```

---

```
var req = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Auth-Identifier': access_token,
  },
  body:file
}
```

use above request in your fetch call. It will work for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try and let you know thank you!

Comment: The uri returned from React native on Android is a "content://" - uri from content provider and FormData does not know how to read that. Any workarounds for this case?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const onSelectFile = async (type) => {
    // Opening Document Picker to select one file
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "File Access",
          message:
            "We Need Your File Access to Upload Resume/Image" ,
           
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      if(granted===PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
        console.log(PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS)
      
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
        // Provide which type of file you want user to pick
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
     
      });
  
    
    
  let formData = new FormData();
 


  formData.append('myfile',{
   uri:res.uri,
   type:res.type,
   name:res.name

  });
  // const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
console.log('FORMDATA',{
  uri:res.uri,
  type:res.type,
  name:res.name

 });


let result = await fetch(
  YOUR_URL',
  {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,

    },
  }
);
let responseJson = await result.json();
console.log('RESPONSE',responseJson)

    } catch (err) {
   
      // Handling any exception (If any)
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        // If user canceled the document selection
        console.log('Canceled');
      } else {
        // For Unknown Error
        console.log('Unknown Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        
      }
    }
  };
```