# express (using multer) Error: Multipart: Boundary not found, request sent by POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, forms, express, multer

**Notice: only when I use form-data body form in Postman (which is the form I have to use because I want to send files beside text fields), I get:**

`Error: Multipart: Boundary not found`.

when I use x-www-form-urlencoded everything is ok. (**ofcourse when body-parser is used as middleware**)

This is Request Content: (made by Postman)

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 61089a44-0b87-0530-ca03-a24374786bd1

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

a simple word
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

good
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

app.post('/test', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.test);
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('app started');
});
```

Comment: if you are having this issue in react native check this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205192/13989650)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I found the solution. I only had to **prevent Postman to send a `Content-Type` header**. So I just removed it from request headers.

Comment: Thank you it works. Can you explain the reason behind this?

Comment: @HassamSaeed https://stackoverflow.com/a/67996268/13328625 I think this answer answers the question

Answer (score 12):

To give some insight on why that is happening,

When using content type `multipart/form-data` in any HTTP request, you can add a boundary information alongside the `Content-Type` specification like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MyBoundary
```

You can replace `MyBoundary` with any string of your liking.

Then you will have to encode your form data (`name=Abebe&age=5`) as:

```
--MyBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Abebe
--MyBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

5
--MyBoundary--
```

For more info read [this StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using fetch method

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/upload_files", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
})
```

headers so that Fetch api automatically set the headers. Now remove headers or "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/upload_files", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
```

Now it works

Answer (score 5):

For **JMeter** and **postman** remove `Content-Type` from **header**.

it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to expand a little bit on user9150719 for those who are having the same issue with the frontend side of things and are wondering where to remove the headers.

I had the same issue; I was trying to post from an Angular app to my Nodejs server. my post request included raw data and a file input. So I was thinking `FormData()`

**Angular Service**

```
//Declare header variables. 

formDataHeader = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this._myService.getToken()
        })
      };

//Post function to Nodejs server
    addNewContact(contact: FormData): any {

        return this._httpClient.post(
          environment.apiBaseUrl + '/contacts', // POST /api/contacts
          (contact), // contact data,
          this.formDataHeader
        );
    }
```

My formData was setup properly. I was able to get all the data, but the problem is that I had setup couple headers in my request that resulted in what user9150719 was experiencing.

My solution was to simplify my headers to this:

```
formDataHeader = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this._myService.getToken()
        })
      };
```

Another important thing to point out is that I didn't need to set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on my `<form></form>` tag.

Even though I had an `httpInterceptor` setup (I don't think it is working properly), I still needed to add the `Authorization` header on all my requests, but all other `headers` were resulting in my api call to return unexpected results.

Finally I think (but I am not entirely sure) that the reason why I didn't need to setup extra headers, is because in my NodeJS server, I already configured what headers to expect.

**Node.JS Server**

```
// app.js

app.use('/public/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-www-form-urlencoded, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, *');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

So I think that if your server is setup to handle certain types of headers (Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, etc.), You don't necessarily need to set those headers again on your frontend when you send your request to the server. There are certain exceptions, such `Authorization` which in certain cases need to be set; probably because they carry some data in the form of `token` or something in that regards.

I hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 2):

Don't mention CONTENT-TYPE header while uploading files from FE using axios/fetch or anything 3rd HTTP handler.

Reason bcoz we don't know the boundary of our files. If you pass only 'multipart/form-data' as Content-Type, you will get an error since we aren't passing boundary in there.

So, let the browser add it (multipart/form-data) along with Boundary based on the files attached.

AND if you want to send some data along with files, you should be sending them as a multipart/form-data(Again we don't need to add this header manually) type only.
We CANNOT send multiple Content-Type data at once for any http call.
Please refer below code.

```js
async onUpload(){
  const formData=new FormData();
  formData.append('files', file1);
  formData.append('files', file2);
  formData.append('data', {key1:value1, key2:value2});
  const res=await axios.post(URL, formData);
}
```

FYI @hassam-saeed

Comment: What if it called from react native mobile app? Then too no need to pass headers?

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone has the same issue i had.

NestJs - BackEnd

NextJs - FrontEnd

I was trying to do something like:

```js
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('context', body.context.toString())
    
body.files.map((file) => {
    formData.append('files', file, `${file.name}`)
})

const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        ...(access_token ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` } : {}),
    },
    body: formData,
})
```

But because this 'Content-Type' overrides the browsers setting of 'Content-Type' AND the content-length is not explicitly set (which was the real issue i think) ,the form-data was showing up on the backend still encoded. So NestJS was not able to parse the 'context' variable or the 'files'.

Also, if you use api routes in NextJS, remeber to check that no-where in there is the 'Content-Type' overridden.... I also had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did this instead

```
const form = new FormData();
headers['Content-Type'] = `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796556/8590519