# Pass Object to Angular FormData

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, form-data

I want to pass **document** field in my form as an object like

```
formData.append('document', {
      uri: this.fileUrl,
      type: this.file.type,
      name: this.file.name
    });
```

There are multiple fields which I use like

```
const formData: any = new FormData();
    sellerType.map(x => {
      formData.append('sellerType', x);
    });
    formData.append('name', this.sellerRegisterForm.value.sellerName);
    formData.append('email', this.sellerRegisterForm.value.email);
    formData.append('password', this.sellerRegisterForm.value.password);
    formData.append('contactNo', this.sellerRegisterForm.value.contactNo);
    formData.append('comp_name', this.companyRegisterForm.value.companyName);
    formData.append('comp_contactNo', this.companyRegisterForm.value.contactNo);
    formData.append('document', {
      uri: this.fileUrl,
      type: this.file.type,
      name: this.file.name
    });
```

but it is not accepting !!
Please anyone can help me with this or if I'm doing anything wrong then please corrent my code that how can I pass this kind of object in formdata...

Comment: Whats the error youre getting ?

Comment: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: but there is also one issue 
when I pass only a single string it will take in the req object but when I pass document as an object it will not take anything in the request header 

it shows 

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"

[object Object]
`

Comment: what is the content type of request header ?

Comment: ` Content-Type: multipart/form-data `

Comment: can you change it to undefined  ?

Comment: @faizal it's not working

Comment: try removing the content type

Comment: Does this answer your issue-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692745/express-using-multer-error-multipart-boundary-not-found-request-sent-by-pos

Comment: @FaizalHussain i tried with removing the content type still it shows 
`document: [object Object]` in request object

Comment: @radhikathakkar as per FormData docs, you can pass either string or Blob object as second argument in append method. Objects are not allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 3 separate fields via formData and need to prepare document object by reading those properties from formData at the API side.

```
formData.set("documentfileUrl", this.fileUrl);
formData.set("documenttype", this.file.type);
formData.set("documentname", this.file.name);
```

API side:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.fileUrl = formData.get("documentfileUrl");
document.type = formData.get("documenttype");
document.name = formData.get("documentname");
```