# Axios. How to upload images with Axios to Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios, multer

I was previously using `ApiSauce` to post listings from `React Native` App to `Node.js` with `Multer`, and now I have migrated to `Axios` everything went fine except for the uploading images part.

```
export const add = (listing, onUploadProgress) => {
const data = new FormData();
data.append('title', listing.title);
data.append('price', listing.price);
data.append('categoryId', listing.category.value);
data.append('description', listing.description);

data.append('userId', listing.userId);

listing.images.forEach((image, index) =>
    data.append('images', {
        name: 'image' + index,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        uri: image,
    }),
);

if (listing.location)
    data.append('location', JSON.stringify(listing.location));

return client.post(endpoint, data, {
    onUploadProgress: (progress) =>
        onUploadProgress(progress.loaded / progress.total),
        
});
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663961/how-do-you-send-images-to-node-js-with-axios

Comment: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found @sonusharma

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692745/express-using-multer-error-multipart-boundary-not-found-request-sent-by-pos).

Comment: it's not helping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you send images to node js with Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663961/how-do-you-send-images-to-node-js-with-axios)

Comment: No  @MukeshMaurya

Comment: what is `client`?

Comment: iOS expo bare work flow. but I had no problem with `ApiSauce`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remove all content type. for multipart boundary  error

try like this rest is handled by multer

```
axios.post(`${subURL}/upload-avatar`, formData, { headers: { "Authorization": jwt } })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err
        })
```