# How to upload a file along with text using fetch in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file to the server using `react-native-document-picker`. The problem I'm facing is I don't know how to upload the file along with a text.In my app there is a portion for file upload also there is an area for writing some text.Then it will get uploaded to the server.So I've done the following.But I'm getting this error after submitting to server

`unhandled promise rejection unsupported BodyInit type`

**updated portion of code**

```
 filepick = () => {
    DocumentPicker.show({
        filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()],
    }, (error, res) => {
        if (error == null) {
            console.log(
                res.uri,
                res.type, // mime type
                res.fileName,
                res.fileSize
            );
            this.setState({
                img_uri: res.uri,
                img_type: res.type,
                img_name: res.fileName

            })
        } else {
            Alert.alert('Message', 'File uploaded failed');
        }
    });
};


 onPressSubmit() {

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', { uri: this.state.img_uri, type: 
       this.state.img_type, name: this.state.img_name })
        data.append('comment', { text: this.state.text });
        AsyncStorage.getItem("userdetail").then(value => {
            fetch(GLOBAL.ASSN_URL +`${this.props.id}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Authorization': value
                },
                body: data
            }).then((response) => {
                return response.text()
            }).then((responseJson) => {
                var result = responseJson;

                console.log(result);

            });
        })
    }
```

The function `filepick()` is called after choosing a file from your device.Please help me to find a solution.How do I upload this to server also how to send text without stringifying it?

Answer (score 0):

```
body: ({
    file: this.state.file,
    comment: this.state.text
})
```

Why are you wrapping body in brackets? Removing them might fix it.

Also see this, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6025 you might want to stringify the body object, since your content type is not `application/json`

```
body: JSON.stringify({
        file: this.state.file,
        comment: this.state.text
})
```

**Edit**

From comments we now know the following

1) You are uploading a file separately.

2) The upload response contains information about the file

3) You are saving the entity in separate server call

4) You need to save file with that entity

The solution below assumes that you have full control over server and you are also handling the file uploading endpoint. Here is the solution

You basically do not need to upload the whole file again with your entity since it is already uploaded on server, all you need to do is to save the reference of the file with entity. Their are two ways to save the reference

**1)** Just save either the fileName or fileUrl in your entity table and then store the name or url with entity so it will look like this

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Cat',
  picture: // url or name of picture
}
```

**2)** Save the uploaded file in different table, then save the id of the file with your entity, and when you fetch entities get the related file. However if the relationship between entity and file is one to many as in one entity can have many files then you will first need to save the entity and then upload the files with reference of entity. This way your entity will look like this

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Cat',
  pictures: [{fileName: 'cat1'}, {fileName: 'cat2'}]
}
```

Comment: No I can't do like this because I'm uploading a file so how can I stringify that file?

Comment: `this.setState({ file: res.fileName })` this line tells me file is actually fileName. Normally we upload the file separately on server and then store the reference (url or name) with the associated entity. Isn't that what you are doing? also what about the brackets?

Comment: Yeah sorry that was my mistake actually I'm trying to upload the entire `res` not `fileName`.So how it will be?

Comment: Yes I've done something like this.But whenever I submit the data I'm getting `Network request failed :unhandled promise rejection`.I've updated my code please help me to find a solution

Comment: `data.append('file', { uri: this.state.img_uri, type: 
       this.state.img_type, name: this.state.img_name })`, you cannot set json object as value of form field I would recommend to use json content type for submission instead of form data

Comment: I got `multipart! = application/json` as error.I'm referencing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188254/discussion-between-umair-abid-and-anu).