# React native fetch post request not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native

According to Instagram API to this is a sample request to get `access_token`.

```
curl -F 'client_id=XXXXXX' \
    -F 'client_secret=XXXXXX' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=XXXXXX' \
    -F 'code=XXXXXX' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

If I run this in the terminal I can get a result that looks something like this:

```
{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "..."
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with react-native.

I am using this code to make a post request on react-native:

```
fetch('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: 'XXXXXX',
    client_secret: 'XXXXXX',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: 'XXXXXX',
    code: 'XXXXXX'
  }),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(obj =>  {
  console.error(obj);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
})
```

And I keep getting a response of `You must provide a client_id.`

I tried to create a jQuery code of this request which **DOES WORK**.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  data: {
    client_id: 'XXXXXX',
    client_secret: 'XXXXXX',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: 'XXXXXX',
    code: 'XXXXXX'
  },
  success: function(html) {
    console.error(html)
  },
  error: function(html) {
    console.error(html)
  }
});
```

A one liner ruby code which also **DOES WORK**

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'), {'client_id': 'XXXXXX','client_secret': 'XXXXXX','grant_type': 'authorization_code','redirect_uri': 'XXXXXX','code': 'XXXXXX'}).body
```

Can you seem to spot what is wrong with my code? It does work with jQuery.

Comment: Try your request with `FormData`? Cause that what `-F` on `curl` means. [This SO answer explains how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37019106/2963461)

Comment: Where did you call `fetch` method? Follow this example https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network .Remember to `return` it inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: @VuLuu I am calling it inside `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Please replace your `fetch` content by: `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))` Is it work?

Comment: @VuLuu Yes get request does work. Also my request to Instagram goes through the only problem is that the parameters does not get passed.

Comment: @wicky Anyway form data does work. Any references I can read for more info about `-F`?

Comment: @DavidAngulo let try with method POST `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers : new Headers(),
                body:JSON.stringify({tittle:tittle, body:body})
            }).then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) =>  console.log(data))
            .catch((err)=>console.log(err))` Does it work?

Comment: @VuLuu It does work. It seems like the problem is my understanding of curl's `-F` function. I can settle with formData for a while.

Comment: @DavidAngulo you can refer to [this docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F), or simply do a `curl --help` on your terminal/command prompt