# How to upload a photo to a backend server along with form data using API?

Tags: api, react-native, image-uploading

Here below is my code, I am trying to capture an image and filling the other input field. Once I click on create button, I am calling an api to upload it to the backend server. But how Do I send the file details to backend? I have the working api in postman. And some of the fields I have not included some of the input field code here because the code will be large here.

API takes the following fields in postman

[image]

```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
        StyleSheet,
        Button,
        TextInput,
        Text,
        TouchableOpacity,
        View,
        Picker,
        Image,
    } from 'react-native';
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

    export default class CreateStudent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                studentName: '',
                email: '',
                newPassword: '',
                fileShow: '',
                faceDetails: '',
                school: 1,
            }
        }

        handleEmail = (text) => {
            this.setState({ email: text })
        }

        handlePassword = (text) => {
            this.setState({ newPassword: text })
        }

        handleName = (text) => {
            this.setState({ studentName: text })
        }

        selectImage = () => {
            const options = {
                quality: 1.0,
                maxWidth: 75,
                maxHeight: 75
            }
            ImagePicker.launchCamera(options,(responce)=>{
                const fileDetails ={
                    uri : responce.uri,
                    name :responce.fileName,
                    method: 'POST',
                    width : 50,
                    height : 50,
                    path : responce.path,
                    type :  responce.type,
                  }
                 this.setState({
                    fileShow: responce.uri,
                    faceDetails: fileDetails
                 })
                console.log(this.state.fileShow);
                console.log(fileDetails);
            })
        }

        async onCreateStudentPressed() {
            try {
                let response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/students/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                       'Accept': 'application/json',
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                         file: this.state.fileDetails,
                         email: this.state.email,
                         password: this.state.newPassword,
                         phone_number: this.state.phoneNumber,
                         class: this.state.class,
                         section: this.state.section,
                         school: this.state.school,
                         name: this.state.studentName
                    })
                });
                let res = await response.text();
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                     //Handle success
                     let accessToken = res;
                     console.log(accessToken);
                     //On success we will store the access_token in the AsyncStorage
                     //this.storeToken(accessToken);
                } else {
                     //Handle error
                     let error = res;
                     throw error;
                }
            } catch(error) {
                this.setState({error: error});
                console.log("error " + error);
                this.setState({
                   passwordUpdated: false
                })
            }
         }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                        <Text style ={styles.pageTitle} >Create Student</Text>
                        <View style={styles.Camera}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectImage}>
                              <Text>Take Picture</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        {
                            this.state.fileShow !== '' ?
                            <View style={styles.showBlack}>
                                <View style={styles.placeholder}>
                                    <Image key={1} source={{uri: this.state.fileShow}} style={styles.previewImage} />
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            :
                            null
                        }
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Enter Student Name'
                            placeholderTextColor='#808080'
                            style ={styles.textInput}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                            onChangeText = {this.handleName}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Enter Student Email'
                            placeholderTextColor='#808080'
                            style ={styles.textInput}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                            onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Enter Password'
                            placeholderTextColor='#808080'
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            style ={styles.textInput}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                            onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}
                        />
                        <Button
                            onPress={this.onCreateStudentPressed.bind(this)}
                            style ={styles.loginBtn}
                            title="Create"
                        />
                    </View>  
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can achieve this. I am going to highlight the easiest way for you to do this. I assume you have a storage service such as Amazon S3 where you store the photo. The easiest way is for you to first upload the image to your S3, the response body will include the url to the uploaded photo. Then you can take that url together with your form values and pass them to your backend.

```
//Example.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        //Whatever RN Components you need
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View,
        Alert,
        TouchableHighlight,
        TextInput,
        ActivityIndicator,
        ScrollView,
        Picker,
        Linking,
        Image,
    } from 'react-native';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

    export default class RegisterScreen extends Component {
    state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmedPassword: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            avatar: '',
            avatarUri: '',
            avatarName: '',
            avatarType: '',
            loading: false,
            errorMessage: '',
            uploadMessage: ''
        }

        onRegisterPress = () => {
            this.setState({ 
                errorMessage: '',
                registerLoading: true,
                uploadMessage: 'This may take a while: Uploading your Profile Pic...'
            });
            const avatarFile = {
                uri: this.state.avatarUri,
                name: this.state.avatarName,
                type: this.state.avatarType
            };
            const avatarOptions = {
                keyPrefix: 'uploads/path/avatar/' + this.state.email + '/' + new Date().getTime(),
                bucket: 'your-bucket-s3',
                region: 'us-west-2',
                accessKey: 'ACCESSKEY',
                secretKey: 'SECRETKEY',
                successActionStatus: 201
            };
            RNS3.put(avatarFile, avatarOptions)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 201) {
                    this.setState({ avatar: response.body.postResponse.location });
                } else {//handle error}
            })
            .then(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        uploadMessage: 'Creating your profile'
                    });
                    const url = 'someremoteurl.com';
                    const payload = {
                        email: this.state.email,
                        password: this.state.password,
                        password_confirmation: this.state.confirmedPassword,
                        first_name: this.state.firstName,
                        last_name: this.state.lastName,
                        avatar: this.state.avatar,
                    };
                    axios.post(url, payload)
                    .then((r) => {
                        this.setState({
                            uploadMessage: '',
                            loading: false
                        });
                        if (r.status === 200) {
                            //handle success
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        // handle form submission error
                        this.setState({
                            uploadMessage: '',
                            loading: false,
                            error: true
                        });
                    });
                });
            }



        openMediaLibrary() {
            const options = {
                title: 'Select Photo',
                storageOptions: {
                    skipBackup: true,
                    path: 'images'
                }
            };
            ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
                console.log('Response = ', response);

                if (response.didCancel) {
                    console.log('Cancelled selection of image');
                } else if (response.error) {
                    console.log('Image Picker error', response.error)
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        avatarUri: response.uri,
                        avatarName: response.fileName,
                        avatarType: response.type
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{ margin: 15 }}>
                    <View style={styles.formField}>
                        <Text style={styles.formLabelStyle}> Email</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='john@yahoo.com'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                            value={this.state.email}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.formField}> 
                        <Text style={styles.formLabelStyle}> Password (minimum of 8 letters)</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='password'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            secureTextEntry
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.formField}> 
                        <Text style={styles.formLabelStyle}> Password Confirmation</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='retype your password'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(confirmedPassword) => this.setState({ confirmedPassword })}
                            value={this.state.confirmedPassword}
                            secureTextEntry
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.formField}> 
                        <Text style={styles.formLabelStyle}> First Name</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='First Name'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState({ firstName })}
                            value={this.state.firstName}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.formField}> 
                        <Text style={styles.formLabelStyle}>Last Name</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Last Name'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(lastName) => this.setState({ lastName })}
                            value={this.state.lastName}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                        {
                            this.state.avatarUri.length > 0 ?
                            <Image 
                                source={{ uri: this.state.avatarUri }}
                                style={{ width: 140, height: 140 }}
                            />
                            : null
                        }
                        </View>
                        <Button 
                            small
                            backgroundColor='#13CE66'
                            title={(this.state.avatarUri.length === 0) ? 
                                'Choose Profile Picture' : 'Change Profile Picture'}
                            onPress={() => this.openMediaLibrary()}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <Button 
                            large
                            backgroundColor='#13CE66'
                            title='Submit'
                            onPress={() => this.onRegisterPress() }
                        />
                </ScrollView>
            )
        }
}
```

So when you attempt to register this user, the image is first uploaded and the retrieved url is stored in state to be used as part of form params for avatar.
This is easy, the downside is having to wait for upload response before actually having to send your form params

### EDIT

If you are not using a 3rd party storage service or if you would rather send the file to your own servers then use `FormData()`:

```
//OnRegisterPress function should look like this:
onRegisterPress = () => {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('avatar', {
        //from openMedia Function, image selected with image-picker
        uri: this.state.avatarUri,
        name: this.state.avatarName,
        type: this.state.avatarType  
    });
    // append your other params such as email, password, name

    form.append('email', this.state.email)
    form.append('password', this.state.password)

    // when you are done appending, use fetch to send the form data as axios seems to be having a bit of issues doing this.

   fetch('http://yourapiendpoint', {  
       headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
       },
       method: 'POST',
       body: form
   });
}
```

Comment: Hey I have already uploaded the images to S3. Now I am creating a user, and when I hit the create button, it calls an api to ping python server. So I am unable to pass file to the python server through api. How can I do it?

Comment: You mean the image file or the url to where the image is hosted? I think you dont need to send the file to your api endpoint if you are already hosting the file on S3. You just need to store the url to the image file when you create a user.  So you can just send the form params to your api endpoint. Are you trying to save the image file itself on your own servers?

Comment: No, it is my requirement. I have to do this. As you can see in the image I have attached of postman, in that I am sending an image and taking in the backend as an whole image instead of path. So I am facing issue in passing image through api. If I send image url, server is throwing error.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Please refer to my updated answer. Scroll down to the EDIT part.

Comment: Why do you suggest uploading the image to S3, instead of uploading the image to backend, and letting it do the S3 upload?

Comment: @BenButterworth I see your point. Uploading to your backend will be best way to do it if you don't use a 3rd party storage or if you intend to save both on your DB and on S3 and I expect OP to have a job in the backend that uploads the file to any storage service and saves the url to the file. The first part of my answer is the easiest way to do this if you do not intend to save media/or any large files on your own DB. But if you intend to send these files to your own server, you might want to use `FormData` and optionally have a job in the backend that uploads them to a 3rd party storage.

Comment: Cool, I was just wondering as I had to make this decision for an application. I chose to upload the photo in the backend as it also needed processing.