# Network request failed in React native using Fetch API

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I'm using fetch API to get data from server using POST method. It return an error: Network request failure. when I try with a Facebook movie API it works good, then I try it with Postman width same key and userId and everything is okay
[image]

this is what I have when I click on the TestAPI button

[image]

this is result in Postman width same configurations

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

Comment: try to use formdata https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

The response that you are showing does not seems to be a JSON object (see the encoding issues) so when you try to do response.json() most likely fails because it can't parse it.

Try to log the response or do response.text() instead of response.json() to try it out.

Seems like your problem is on your php server code.

Comment: now I receive a Json answer from server but not the right answer.