# FormData with ExpressJS with image and body data

Tags: react-native, express, multer

Hello I want to ask a question about using form data to send a file and also update data from user at the same time in ExpressJS. I want to ask if this could be handle all in one using form data (save image and update a profile information) through axios or should it be handle in two (two HTTP Requests)? For example:

```
formData.append('file', {
        uri: file.uri,
        type: file.type,
        name: file.name,
      });
// and append for example a updated info
formData.append('profileUpdate', {
            name: newName,
            email: newEmail, 
            age: newAge,
          });
```

then receive it on the express route side and separate each other or can you even do it with form-data request? or is there a way I can send the body apart on a PUT or POST Request (form-data)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use FormData in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native)

Comment: Yes part of it thank you, how can I receive on express side?

Comment: Using Multer. The uploaded file will be in `req.file` and everything else in `req.body`

Comment: Okay thank you, so much for answering my question. Didn't have much experience using form-data, so thank you so much!