react native fetch Post with FormData throws SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: N
I am sending a post with the following details along with multiple images as form data:
  let form = new FormData();

  form.append('img1', imgArray[0]);
  form.append('img2', imgArray[1]);
  form.append('img3', imgArray[2]);
  form.append('price', selectedprice);
  form.append('seller_id', id);
  form.append('type', selectedvalue);
  form.append('category', 'care');
  form.append('from_date', startdate);
  form.append('to_date', enddate);
  form.append('discription', description);
  console.log('form data====>', form);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: form,
    redirect: 'follow',
  };


  fetch('http://base_url/api/upload-products', requestOptions)
    .then((response) =>
      response.json()
    ).then(res => console.log('UPLOAD res===>', res))
    .catch(error =>
      console.log('error==catch>', error));
});

After hitting this API I'm getting the below error in the catch block:
 [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: N]

and then API response 400, however, this API is working well in Postman. Previously I was sending single image with this API, later on we updated API with multiple images as well but I have issues this time.
here is postman API screenshot .
and this is how my formData looks:
 {"_parts": [["img1", "file:///data/user/0/com.appName/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_7eb48acb-2b5e-4ed9-9b20-b7d8293001cd.jpg"], ["img2", "file:///data/user/0/com.appName/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_a8241f47-2d9c-4717-8994-e711a8f22dad.jpg"], ["img3", "file:///data/user/0/com.appName/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_b9a00c94-03de-43eb-ac08-1e4a3a38a22b.jpg"], ["price", "79"], ["seller_id", "65c71746fcf33d49d3334d10"], ["type", "machine"], ["category", "health care"], ["from_date", "17-04-2024"], ["to_date", "17-04-2024"], ["discription", "Ns"]]}

Please help me here. Thanks

Without details of API it is impossible to say what is wrong with the request.

@user18309290  I have updated postman ss

Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native

@Srikanth Thanks it really helped, I forgot to add image as object {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'}

I need to update image sending in formData as:
{uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'}

So Once you add image ion formdata it shoud go as an object along with all these values.
Final formData:
{"_parts": [["img1", [Object]], ["img2", [Object]], ["img3", [Object]], ["price", "55"], ["seller_id", "65c71746fcf33d49d3334d10"], ["type", "machine"], ["category", "health"], ["from_date", "18-04-2024"], ["to_date", "18-04-2024"], ["discription", "Bbb"]]} 

